# MATLAB - obtain the object a property belongs to?

Tags: oop, matlab

Suppose I have a `myClass < handle` with property `A`. If I create an instance of `myClass`, say `myObj`, and pass `myObj.A` to a function, say `function myFunc(val)`, is it possible within `myFunc` to see that the `val` passed to it is a property of `myObj`?

EDIT: For context:

I'm writing an API (in a sense) to interface with Arduino hardware for my research lab. The overarching class is called `Vehicle`, with properties `PinManager < handle`, `TelemCollector < handle`, and various `Device < handle`s. It also has methods to do things like `runMotor()`, `getAltitude()`, etc. I have a method `TelemCollector.telemFetch()` which is the callback for a timer event; I would like `TelemCollector.telemFetch()` to be able to access `Vehicle` methods (namely `getAltitude()`); naively I would just make `Vehicle` a property of `TelemCollector` to access those methods. I was hoping to not have to do this.

EDIT2: Sample code snippet of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
classdef Vehicle < handle
    properties
        PinManager
        TelemCollector
        Devices
    end
    methods
        function obj = Vehicle(PM, TC, D)
            obj.TC = TelemCollector();
            obj.PM = PinManager();
            obj.Devices = D();
        end 
        function val = getAltitude(obj)
            %# read altitude from a connected Device
        end
        function val = getSpeed(obj)
            %# read speed from connected Device
        end
    end
 end

 classdef TelemCollector < handle
     properties
         %# ...
     end
     methods
         function fetchTelem(obj)
             %# do getAltitude(), getSpeed(), etc, here.. but I want to access
             %# Vehicle.getAltitude() and Vehicle.getSpeed() somehow!
         end
     end
 end
```

Comment: I don't quite understand - first you say Vehicle has a property of class TelemCollector, and at you end you say you are thinking about giving TelemCollector a property of type Vehicle?? If telemFetch() needs to access internals of both objects, it needs to be a method of the "outer" object, not the inner one to make it work.

Comment: ... maybe you could post an actual code snippet instead of a textual description; that would be easier to understand...

Comment: added code snippet to OP. I wanted `telemFetch()` to access `Vehicle` methods; this is doable if the `Vehicle` that `TelemCollector` is a property of is a property of `TelemCollector`. since everything is a handle, they'll refer to the proper object instances. Of course, I really don't want to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all I know, no.

For example if `myObj.A` is a double, myFunc will just be passed the value it contains and there will be no reference to the object. If you were calling `myFunc(somevariable)` where `somevariable` was really the name of a variable and not an expression, then calling [`inputname(1)`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/inputname.html) inside of `myFunc` would give you the string 'somevariable', but since you are referring to a property of a class, this is too complicated for MATLAB and `inputname(1)` just returns `''` (tested with MATLAB R2011a).

*Update*: Why do you need to know this anyhow? If your interfaces are cleanly designed, you should probably not have to do this kind of thing. Or are you trying to work around someone else's bug/bad design? Depending on your application you could think of some kind of very dirty hack involving `dbstack`, trying to find out which m-file called your function, read the appropriate line of code from the .m file, parse it and then access the object using `evalin('caller',...)` ... but I doubt that's a good idea ;-).

**Edit** in response to context you provided:

Can't you just redefine your Timer callback to hand over the "Vehicle" object as well? i.e.

```
set(yourtimer_handle,'TimerFcn',{@fetchTelem,vehicle_handle});
```

means that whenever the callback timer calls the function TelemCollector.fetchTelem(), it hands over vehicle_handle as a third argument [as described in the docu](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-39541.html#f9-39598). This works in conjunction with a changed function head

```
function fetchTelem(obj, event, vehicle_handle)
```

where you can replace `event` by `~` in newer MATLAB versions if you don't need it.

Could that work?

Comment: You would just pass in vehicle_handle to the TelemCollector constructor, right? Thanks for the help. As I wrote to Nzbuu, I didn't implement your answer but instead slightly rewrote the interface. It's good to know that this doable (albeit not the prettiest thing). Man, I wish MATLAB had friend classes..

Comment: With my solution the TelemCollector constructor wouldn't need to have the vehicle handle, as long as you set up the callback somewhere where you have access to the vehicle. The *callback* would then have the vehicle handed to it. But this is specific to your case where you said fetchTelem is called by a timer, so if Nzbuu's solution doesn't pose other problems for you, that is surely the more general and equally clean solution :-).

Answer (score 2):

fetchTelem can't call methods of an object that it doesn't have a reference to. So, regardless, you need to provide your TelemCollector object with the Vehicle handle.

Personally, I think the association between Vehicle and TelemCollector should be in the opposite direction. I would prefer something that looked more like:

```
V = Vehicle(PM, D);
TC = TelemCollector(V);
```

Although it really depends on how you expect to use the classes.

I agree with @Jonas Heidelberg: if it's this difficult, then it's probably the wrong interface.

Comment: This is the route I ended up taking; I gave the checkmark to Jonas Heidelberg since it best answers the actual question, but from a design standpoint it makes much more sense your way. I agree, this is a difficult problem and it require(d) a rethink of how I'm putting the classes together.

Comment: +1 ... this is a more general solution to what was behind the original question.